# C# Autocomplete textbox dropdown height

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I have a textbox in my winforms project which as part of a table holds a description of some material a company will buy. To ensure that the company enforces consistent naming, I have implemented autocomplete on the textbox as so:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(pastItems);
desc.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
desc.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
desc.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

I know that with a combobox you can set the maximum size of the dropdown menu, but so far I cannot find a way to do this for my textbox. Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454638/3392285 Take a look at this answer here.

Comment: Hmmm I did come across this, but I was hoping for a better way to do it such as getting accessing the current dropdown