# How to change the position of Auto-Complete List at an absolute position with a defined height and width?

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, combobox

I wish to change the position of auto-complete list and the height and width of the same. I wish to do the same to datagridviewcombobox

I have already tried the control to show the autocomplete list

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl Then
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        CType(e.Control, ComboBox).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

    End If
End Sub
```

The autocomplete list gets populated just below the control.
I wish it to display at the right side of the screen
[image: The Auto-suggest list]

Comment: I wish to change the physical location. Like the X and Y axis of the control

Comment: It appears that you can't do this. Multiple search results suggest that. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454638/832052. My inclination was to hijack the Graphics object associated with the dropdown but I can't find it in any event of the TextBox (if the dropdown were a standard ListBox it would be quite simple). I think you will need to make your own listbox pop up and code the filtering and selection logic.